MacOS python 3.9 No module named 'distutils.msvccompiler'
I'm trying to install scikit-learn==1.0 in a virtualenv that I created via pipenv on my Mac.
But I get the following error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.msvccompiler'

setuptool version is 69.5.1. I even tried with lower version 59.1 still didn't help.
This issue doesn't occur in Windows, so I wonder how using Mac can impact this?
The full print of error is:
Collecting scikit-learn==1.0
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.0.tar.gz (7.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/FFIROUZA/.local/share/virtualenvs/predmaint-5-6S7_mY/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/FFIROUZA/.local/share/virtualenvs/predmaint-5-6S7_mY/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Users/FFIROUZA/.local/share/virtualenvs/predmaint-5-6S7_mY/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/yw/w0vbj__56k7gswchtmvkr_fc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-040c2b1w/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 376, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/yw/w0vbj__56k7gswchtmvkr_fc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-040c2b1w/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 521, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/private/var/folders/yw/w0vbj__56k7gswchtmvkr_fc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-040c2b1w/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 319, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 319, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 311, in setup_package
        File "/private/var/folders/yw/w0vbj__56k7gswchtmvkr_fc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-040c2b1w/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 24, in <module>
          from numpy.distutils.command import config, config_compiler, \
        File "/private/var/folders/yw/w0vbj__56k7gswchtmvkr_fc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-040c2b1w/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/config.py", line 19, in <module>
          from numpy.distutils.mingw32ccompiler import generate_manifest
        File "/private/var/folders/yw/w0vbj__56k7gswchtmvkr_fc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-040c2b1w/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/mingw32ccompiler.py", line 29, in <module>
          from distutils.msvccompiler import get_build_version as get_build_msvc_version
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.msvccompiler'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.


The error is interesting because msvccompiler is specifically a Windows-related module (Microsoft Visual C++ compiler). The fact that you're seeing this on Mac suggests there might be an issue with how the package is trying to build.
Do you have Xcode Command Line Tools installed?

Yes, I have it installed

Maybe try and specify the compiler explicitly:
export CC=/usr/bin/clang export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++ pip install scikit-learn==1.0
The key difference between Mac and Windows here is that scikit-learn requires compilation of C++ extensions, and the build system might be getting confused about which compiler to use. On Windows, it looks for MSVC, while on Mac it should be using clang.

Thanks for the explanations. I don't know why but I still get the same error...

I'm going to work with the latest version of scikit-learn as the error for this one doesn't appear. Your comment has been helpful. Thanks!

As mentioned in the comments, the key difference between Mac and Windows here is that scikit-learn requires compilation of C++ extensions, and the build system might be getting confused about which compiler to use. On Windows, it looks for MSVC, while on Mac it should be using clang.
It seems that scikit-learn==1.0 is only compatible with MSVC and not clang. Therefore upgrading to a later scikit-learn version is the only solution. scikit-learn==1.0.2 is the earliest version compatible.


From Python 3.10 onwards, distutils has been deprecated. So use
lower versions like 3.9 or below if scikit-learn==1.0 requires it.

setting the compiler to clang helps prevent scikit-learn from trying to use the Windows-specific msvccompiler.
export CC=clang
pip install scikit-learn==1.0


Use Python 3.9 or lower,to avoid several issues with distutils and scikit-learn dependencies:
[requires]
python_version = "3.9"


Check out for latest setuptools and wheel packages installed, as this often resolves cross-platform compatibility issues.
pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel


At last in order to avoid pre-built binaries that might reference msvccompiler, use pip to install scikit-learn directly from the source:
pipenv run pip install --no-binary :all: scikit-learn==1.0




I've tried them all, still get exact same message as before.
